# Is Pylons still worth learning?

Tags: pylons

I know that Pylons is discontinued as such and is imported to Pyramid. However, I really like to learn Pylons and could not make my way through Pyramid (which is still rather premature and lacks begginer-friendly docs) so I started to read the [online](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1) Pylons book, which I think only covers Pylons 0.97 and some of examples (like the one about '[environ](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/exploring-pylons.html#understanding-how-http-works)') did need work for me (in Pylons 1.0) So I seem to have some bumpers in my learning curve that led me to wonder whether it really worth the effort.

Comment: well, that's a personal opinion, will be hard to find an answer for this, in the team where I work, first we choose pylons over django, because of its simplicity. Then when pyramid 1.0 was born we check it out, and we stay in pylons :P, personally I like pylons and I will continue developing on it, it's known that pylons will only have some bug fixing but there's no plans for pylons 2.0 read the following post for more info: http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/97faa18a3429a28e?pli=1

Comment: pyramid isn't exactly premature. it's plenty production hardened as repoze.bfg which came before it. I will agree with you on the lack of beginner friendly docs. though that isn't the intent of pyramid anyway.  as webjunkie says below, if you want to learn pyramid in more of a pylons context try Akhet.

Comment: pylons is more begginer-friendly but pyramid has better doc. if you choose to learn pylons you won't be sorry and you will also have no problems migrating to pyramid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pylons is a very mature framework and you can develop sophisticated web applications with it. Although the docs are outdated you can still learn from them with a few tweaks and looking into the updated [cookbook](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Home). The difference between Pylons and Pyramid are the merge of repoze.bfg and turbogears which brings more API resources. If you come from a Pylons background and want to learn Pyramid you should take a look at [Akhet](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/akhet/dev/).